# remove elements based on external file

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an external setting file which has some nodes holiding attribute values of main xml document. I need to remove certian nodes from mian xml file if the attribute value is there in the setting file.

My setting file looks like this:

setting.xml

```
 <xml>
     <removenode titlename="abc" subtitlename="xyz"></removenode>
     <removenode titlename="dvd" subtitlename="dvd"></removenode>

 </xml>
```

Main.xml

```
<xml>
     <title titlename="abc">
         <subtitle subtitlename="xyz"></subtitle>
      </title>
      <title titlename="book">
          <subtitle subtitlename="book sub title"></subtitle>
      </title>
 </xml>
```

Need a script which look for setting.xml file and remove the title element if titlename and subtitlename found in main.xml. The output should be

output.xml

```
 <xml>
      <title titlename="book">
          <subtitle subtitlename="book sub title"></subtitle>
      </title>
 </xml>
```

I tried using document to read setting.xml file but not able to find how to do the match on main.xml file

```
 <xsl:variable name="SuppressionSettings" select="document('Setting.xml')" />
    <xsl:variable name="SuppressSetting" select="$SuppressionSettings/xml/removenode" />
```

.

Any hint how to implement it?

Comment: What happens when you try your code with `document()`?

Comment: i gets the values from external file but not sure how to write a match template for main.xml i.e   <xsl:template match="title = ??/ and subtile=????">

Comment: Your *Main.xml* and *output.xml* are not well-formed. Please correct this so future readers can reproduce the problem along with the answer (that I'm about to post).

Comment: Thanks, response posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use an identity/copy pattern and, before each output, check the current (context) node isn't prohibited by the suppression rules nodeset.

```
    <!-- get suppression settings -->
    <xsl:variable name='suppression_settings' select="document('http://www.mitya.co.uk/xmlp/settings.xml')/xml/removenode" />


    <!-- begin identity/copy -->

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:if test='not($suppression_settings[@titlename = current()/@titlename and @subtitlename = current()/subtitle/@subtitlename])'>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select='node()|@*' />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

You can run it here (see output source - the 'abc' title node is omitted):

http://www.xmlplayground.com/9oCYKp

Comment: Thanks Marzipan, if I interchange the subtitlename values in setting file it still suppress the title where as it should not unless the titlename and subtitlename matchs within the same node. The problem with above code is that it looks for any removenode value which has titlename and subtitlename independetly. Where as it should look for both the values from same node.

Comment: Edited. Getting warmer yet? :)

Comment: Thank you It worked , it's already too hot here so avoiding that :).

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT indicated below works for the given document.

Note that I'm storing the contents of *Setting.xml* in a variable as you did, however, I'd then use that variable directly in my queries.

An important issue here is that in the `match` element of a `template`, variables cannot be used. Therefore, my template matches any `<title>` elements and then determines in an `<xsl:choose>` element whether the attributes match any values given in the settings file - if so, the `<title>` element will be omitted in the output.

As an explanation for why that `test` attribute in the `<xsl:when>` does what it should, imagine a comparison of `someAttribute = someOtherAttribute` not as a restriction that *the attribute `someAttribute` must have the same value as the attribute `someOtherAttribute`*, but rather as the condition that *there must be any two attributes `someAttribute` and `someOtherAttribute` with the same value*.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="SuppressionSettings" select="document('Setting.xml')" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//title">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="(@titlename = $SuppressionSettings/xml/removenode/@titlename) and (subtitle/@subtitlename = $SuppressionSettings/xml/removenode/@subtitlename)"/>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Problem with this is that if setting file has below values then it will also suppress the title. Where as it should not suppress in case of below setting files. <removenode titlename="abc" subtitlename="dvd"></removenode> <removenode titlename="dvd" subtitlename="xyz"></removenode>

Comment: so i just interchange the subtitlename values in setting file and it still suppress the title where as it should not unless the titlename and subtitlename matchs within the same node.

Comment: @atif: Oh, right, it doesn't look for the attribute values in the same settings node. Sorry. As another answer has already shown the correct version, I'm going to leave it at this now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more generic answer where the names of the attributes are not hard coded into the XSLT. Like O. R. Mapper pointed out, in XSLT 1.0 you can't use variable references in the `match`, so I put the `document()` directly in the predicate. This may not be as efficient as using a variable and then testing the variable.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@* = document('setting.xml')/*/removenode/@*]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output** (using your 2 xml files with main.xml as the input)

```
<xml>
   <title titlename="book">
      <subtitle subtitlename="book sub title"/>
   </title>
</xml>
```

Comment: It didnt look for subtitlename. so not what i am look for.